# Building modules with linux kernel for custom flavor

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I followed the [instructions for building a custom kernel](http://blog.avirtualhome.com/how-to-compile-a-new-ubuntu-11-04-natty-kernel/) and booting it. Everything works fine, except that when building it, I used the option `skipmodule=true` (as given in this link), so I guess the modules are not built for this kernel.

I'm saying this because after I installed the image (using `dpkg -i`), when I run `ls -l` in the `/lib/modules/2.6.38-11-i5` folder, all the files/folders except the 'kernel' folder have got updated (Btw, I had built it last time and it had worked fine,this is an update on the same kernel source).

So is there some option/command that I missed that export the modules as well?

Answer (score 0):

Okay. It works fine.

Actually, my module was getting exported to `/lib` when I installed the new kernel image. Guess the timestamp of the parent directory `/lib/modules/2.6.38-11-i5/kernel` doesn't get updated.